# Unable to create UML C# class diagrams in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml, reverse-engineering

I am unable to create the UML class diagram for my C# code in VS 2010 ultimate for unknown reason, I searched the internet and found that I need to download the [Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff655021.aspx) but the site is not working for me.

So is there another tool/application to create UML diagrams for my code rather than VS 2010 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try **UMLet** , a Free UML Tool for Fast UML Diagrams.
You can find more about it from the link below.

http://www.umlet.com/

Or you can try **NClass** also.

http://nclass.sourceforge.net/downloads.html

Comment: Its only for creating diagrams from scratch and not from excited code as I require